# Laravel 5 Permiso

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement this package in Laravel 5:

https://github.com/ricardoriogo/Permiso

I have followed the instructions and the package has installed correctly but I am unable to get it to work.

I am required to add the UserRolesTrait to the User model like so:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    use Riogo\Permiso\UserRolesTrait;
    ...
}
```

but when I run a simple migration it tells me Trait 'App\Models\Riogo\Permiso\UserRolesTrait' not found. Why not?

L5 doesn't seem to know where the file is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Prepend a backslash, `\Riogo\Permiso\..`

Comment: That worked thanks but how do you seed the roles? The Role model is buried away in the package and there isn't even a model for User_role.

Comment: A model for user_roles shouldn't be needed as it's a relationship table. You seed them via a seeder class?